# How to pass a value of javascript variable on button click to jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have generated a number randomly to be concatenated with a string like below:

```
var pid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
var str = "PERSONS";
var id = str.concat(pid);
```

I have a div section in the HTML with a button like this:

```
<div>
    <h4>name</h4>
    <button OnClick='display(id);'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display(id) {
        var a = id;
        alert(a); 
    }
</script>
```

When I click the button inside the div section, I want to pass the value of ID which is generated randomly for this particular name, and delete the particular name from the database using AJAX.

How do I pass the corresponding ID value when the button is clicked? The ID value is generated randomly in JavaScript and not in PHP.

Comment: What database? Where is your click function? Where is any JS beside the random thing?

Comment: use data-* attribute to store the values in button, and give the button an ID and use it.

Comment: data-* attribute ?

Comment: What do you mean by "generated randomly for this particular name"? There's just one global variable, how is it connected to a particular name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```js
var pid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
var str = "PERSONS";
var id = str.concat(pid);
function display() {
     var a =id;
     alert(a); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><h4>name</h4><button OnClick='display();'>Delete</button></div>
```

Comment: what is this id_1,id_2...? In mine i want to pass the value of a javascript  variable to that particular function ..

Comment: @seena, what is result?

Answer (score 0):

Given this part of the question:

> for this particular name

I'll assume you have multiple div sections, each needs a random "id" assigned.

1. give the buttons a class (the same class) so that they can be referenced via jquery (or you could apply to the wrapper div, on the button for clarity, this assumes you have other buttons so don't want to change all buttons)
2. assign the random id to the button via script
3. change the onclick to pass the element/html-node rather than the id

html:

```
<div>
    <h4>name1</h4>
    <button type="button" class='randomid' onclick='display(this);'>Delete</button>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>name2</h4>
    <button type="button" class='randomid' onclick='display(this);'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

jquery (this assumes the html is not generated dynamically after this has been called):

```
$(function() {
    $("button.randomid").each(function() {
        var pid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
        var str = "PERSONS";
        var id = str.concat(pid);
        $(this).data("randomid", id);
    });
});    

function display(el) {
    var id = $(el).data("randomid");
    alert(id);
}
```